# Diploria labyrinthiformis - can we reproduce Ernst Haeckel's drawing of a brain coral?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, generative-art, fractals

Ernst Haeckel (1834 - 1919) was a German philosopher, physician, artist and professor of zoology at the University of Jena. He promoted and popularised Charles Darwin's work in Germany.

[image]

*Haeckel (left) with Nicholai Miklukho - Maklai, his assistant, in the Canaries, 1866*

The published artwork of Haeckel includes over 100 detailed, multi-colour illustrations of animals and sea creatures, collected in his famous "Art Forms of Nature", which is still published in various languages. As I was recently browsing through the book, I was struck by his depiction of [Scleratina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scleractinia) corals, because their beautiful structures are so "mathematical".

[image]

The middle one, a "Diploria labyrinthiformis", also called "brain coral", seemed to be a good start for a "Mathematica replica".

[image]

From my collection of mathematical surfaces I picked up this [Gyroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroid) - like structure which looks like a coral skeleton:

```
gyro = 
  10 (Cos[x] Sin[y] + Cos[y] Sin[z] + Cos[z] Sin[x]) -
   0.5 (Cos[2 x] Cos[2 y] + Cos[2 y] Cos[2 z] + Cos[2 z] Cos[2 x]) - 12;

n = 8;
ContourPlot3D[gyro == 0, {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}, {z, -n, n},
 Axes -> False,
 Background -> GrayLevel[0],
 Boxed -> False,
 ContourStyle -> White,
 Lighting -> "Accent",
 Mesh -> 0,
 PlotPoints -> 15]
```

[image]

I was curious to see what it would look like if I gave him a rounded form:

```
ContourPlot3D[gyro, {x, y, z} \[Element] Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 8],
 Axes -> False,
 Background -> GrayLevel[0],
 Boxed -> False,
 ContourStyle -> White,
 Lighting -> "Accent",
 Mesh -> 0,
 PlotPoints -> 5,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Disappointing, and certainly not the way to go!

[Robert Fathauer](http://www.robertfathauer.com/index.html), one of the leading mathematical artists, took a different way when he produced this ceramic brain coral sculpture:

[image]

His explanation:

*"This sculpture, created in 2014, is based on the first three generations of a fractal curve that develops radially outward. The starting point is a simple saddle, and the final form has an envelope that is roughly hemispherical. The space curves were created by fitting a series of planar fractal curves to the surface of an octahedron. This fractal structure possesses two-fold rotational symmetry. The sculpture, which was partly inspired by brain coral, measures 21" in width and 11" in height."*

Sounds frightening complicated to me, and so I would like to ask:

**How would you create a brain coral?**

**Addendum 1**

Similar to Silvia's comment:

[image]

[American Mathematical Society](https://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/math-imagery/taimina)

**Addendum 2**

Please also have a look at [Repulsive Curves](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3439429) by Henrik Schumacher et al. (see his comment), especially 14:50, page 41, where the authors show Hilbert-curve-like patterns meandering on a sphere. Also interesting:

[Interpolating the Hilbert Curve with a B-Spline](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/InterpolatingTheHilbertCurveWithABSpline/)

Comment: Well, my collaborators and I played a bit with the idea to maximize the length of the curve inscribed into a sphere under some self-avoidance constraint (which we built in via using the so-called tangent-point energy). See, e.g., Fig. 24 in https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3439429. The numerics of solving this problem is quite involved. But I have some _Mathematica_ code for it. (It is just to long to post it here, I am afraid.)

Comment: Might be of interest for OP: [Crocheting Adventures with Hyperbolic Planes](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~dtaimina/hypplanes.htm).

Comment: Thank you, Silvia, I added a similar thing to the question :)

Comment: Interesting and challenging question. I hope you will get some nice answers. But, please, do not close the question soon, some people may need time to produce good solutions.

Comment: Thanks, Henrik for sharing your extremely interesting video. I added the link to my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not quite there, but this could be a basis for a better answer that does a line sweep along the B-Spline.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
n = 1000;
pts = Normalize /@ (SpherePoints[n] + RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.025], n]);
st = pts[[Last@FindShortestTour[pts]]];
Graphics3D[Tube[BSplineCurve[st], .08], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: brain]

Answer (score 8):

- Still not so good.

```
ContourPlot3D[ (Cos[x] Sin[y] + Cos[y] Sin[z] + Cos[z] Sin[x] == 
     0 /. {x -> 2 x, y -> 2 y, z -> 2 z}) // Evaluate, {x, -8, 
  8}, {y, -8, 8}, {z, -8, 8}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 8^2 && z >= 0], 
 ContourStyle -> White, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotTheme -> {"ThickSurface"}, Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

An attempt at a coral like brain:

I have 8GB of RAM so choosing better settings for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` hangs up my system.

```
uhemi = RegionIntersection[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 8, 8}], 
   Cuboid[{-6, -8, 0}, {6, 8, 8}]];

ContourPlot3D[Cos[2 x  y] + Sin[2 y  z] + Sin[2 z x] == 0
 , {x, y, z} \[Element] uhemi
 , Boxed -> False
 , BoxRatios -> Automatic
 , Axes -> False
 , Mesh -> None
 , ContourStyle -> Directive[
   Lighter@ColorData["HTML"]["Chocolate"]
   , Opacity[0.5]
   , Specularity[1, 20]
   ]
 , PlotPoints -> 15
 , Extrusion -> 0.2
 , MaxRecursion -> 1
 , RegionBoundaryStyle -> None
 , BoundaryStyle -> Lighter@Brown
 , NormalsFunction -> None
 , Lighting -> "Neutral"
 , ImageSize -> 800
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: You're surely worthy of and deserve more than 8 GiB, @Syed :)